# How to convert a URL image to BLOB in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

My problem is to convert a URL like http://example.org/image.png which is in a varchar column, to another column as blob, to store the image in this very same table, using only mysql.
My main goal is to store this image in my table, because this URL may expire and the image may not be available anymore.
So, not only convert the content of the column A VARCHAR but get the image, convert it to BLOB ans store it in the BLOB column...
is it possible? HOW??

Comment: How is the url getting into your database - are you using PHP or another Programming language to find/store the url?

Comment: Im getting it by a API using NODE, which stores in this column the URL only. When I want to present it in the REACT, It does call the URL directly.

Comment: I think you should be able to follow this article to get the file into a blob to store in your DB  - this article also covers converting it into an image to display: https://dev.to/dnature/convert-a-base64-data-into-an-image-in-node-js-3f88

Comment: So, you mean I cant read a URL file content from Mysql and store the BLOB converted info from it directly using Mysql?

Comment: This way, I would have to read the file in NODE, buffer it, convert then write to the database, is that it?

Comment: This method is valid to read a URL in the internet or just for local files?

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

On my understanding you can do this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
// Reads file in form buffer =>
var image_url='http://example.org/image.png';
const buffer = fs.readFileSync("path-to-image.jpg");
```

At this stage write your buffer (string) to your database. Then sometime later you can load your string and pass it to this function and store the image locally.

```
var buffer = 'fetch your string from your database';
fs.writeFileSync("new-path.jpg", buffer);
```

If you can point the code to a "local" url it should be able to do the same thing. (your last comment/question)

Full discolosure I have never worked with Node. But I cannot see a reason why you would really want to store this in your DB, and not just download it locally?